# Is there any way to query meta data of systems views in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, repository

We can use system views (metadata of the current database) in SQL Server to query tables, columns, FK... But is there any way to query metadata of systems views to list for example all columns of system vies, relationship between system views?

I can find a pdf but I cannot find the way to query directly from SQL Server.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39083

Answer (score 2):

Those views are exposed in the `sys.system_views` catalog view (`schema_id = 4` is the `sys.` schema):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.system_views
WHERE name = 'tables'
AND SCHEMA_ID = 4
```

Result:

[image]

Once you have the `object_id` of the system catalog view you're interested in, you can e.g. check it columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.system_columns
WHERE OBJECT_ID = -386
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can we also find the relationship between those views from a system view?